# Modify Firebase notification to replace phone number with contact name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am working on an android chat app with firebase. As a notification, I am getting Phone number of the sender and the and the message. Is it possible to modify the Notification using background Service?

I am trying below code. When app is in foreground, I am able to modify the title. How can I add contact name in the title.
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_ID_EXTRA = "notificationId";
    private static final String IMAGE_URL_EXTRA = "imageUrl";
    private static final String ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID ="admin_channel";
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }


    private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Log.d("service", messageBody);
        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                        .setContentTitle("Will set contact name here")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("channel description");
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            channel.canShowBadge();
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```